# How do I upload an MP3 held in state via Fetch to a Next.JS API Route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, next.js

I have a voice-recorder that records user-audio and stores it as `state` in a ReactJS component. When I pass the file to my API route it is recognised as a `string` and I don't seem to be able to upload it to AWS S3 correctly.

Here is the ReactJS button Handler:

```
  const [audioFile, setAudioFile] = useState(null)

  ...
  const submitVoiceMemo = async () => {
    console.log('this is the payload', audioFile)
    // the file is named 'audio.mp3'

    try {
      await fetch('/api/createVoiceMemo', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: audioFile
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

However, when the file 'arrives' at the API Route it is a `string` and I don't know how to convert it back to an `MP3`:

```
module.exports = requireAuth(async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body) 
    // this prints 'characters' the to the console and is typeof string
```

I also can't seem to restructure `req.body` - if I try to `console.log(req.body.audioFile)` I get `undefined`.

How do I format the file so that I can upload it as an MP3 to AWS S3?

Comment: Seems like this library might help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-decode In general though, you might want to read up on buffering and decoding files in node. Here's an article to start https://dzone.com/articles/uploading-and-downloading-files-buffering-in-nodej

Comment: I checked out the link. I 'think' `req.body` is returning a stream, but I'm not sure how to convert that readable stream into an `MP3` file.

Comment: `req.audioFile` is not going to be thing. Because it's a stream, whatever content you are sending will come in "chunks". In the above link's code example, they use event handlers like `req.on('data', (chunk) => {//do something with the chunk})`, `req.on('end', () => {//here you would save the file because you've got all the data})`.  You can read about event emitters here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter.

Comment: @arfi720 I tried passing `req.body` directly: `s3Params: ... Body: 'req.body' ...`, but the file that ends up in `AWS S3` doesn't play. I'm not really sure how to convert the incoming `req.body` string (which I cannot destructure), into an `MP3` again.